# How to call ApiResource with middleware in my routes?

Tags: laravel, middleware

When I use `middleware` like below, no problem:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

But if I try to use it with `apiResources`, like below:

```
Route::apiResources([
    'user' => 'API\UserController',
    'posts' => 'API\PostController'
])->middleware('auth:api');
```

Then I get an error message:

> php artisan route:list
>
> BadMethodCallException
>
> Method Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar::apiResources does not
>   exist.

What is the correct way to call `ApiResource` with `middleware` in `routes/api.php` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can add any middleware's to the `apiResources`, what you could do instead is nest them inside a route group that applies them

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::apiResources([
        'user' => 'API\UserController',
        'posts' => 'API\PostController'
    ]);
});
```

This would also allow you to shorten the controller definitions with the [namespace](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-group-namespaces) option:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api', 'namespace' => 'API'], function () {
    Route::apiResources([
        'user' => 'UserController',
        'posts' => 'PostController'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! With `php artisan route:list`, I see in the `middleware` column `api,auth:api`, does it mean that I can also access this route without being authenticated (via `api`) ? But then `auth:api` would be useless...

Comment: @DevonDahon No, it just lists you the middleware's this route has to pass through. In this case the `api` middleware group which you can find in  `app\Http\Kernel.php` and the `auth:api` middleware. The route has to pass through all of them, so it will only be accessible for authenticated users.